# Justification of modular law in allegories

Tags: ct.category-theory, intuition, definitions

The modular law in modular lattices can be described as an isomorphism between opposite edges of the square $(a \land b), a, b, (a\lor b)$.  A fancier way of saying this is an adjoint equivalence with the two functors $(-\land b), (-\lor a)$.

Is there a similar description of the modular law in the definition of [allegories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/allegory)? It holds in the category of sets and relations, and is certainly a generalization of the lattice modular law. But is there a stronger justification why it should be included in the definition? Does it naturally pop out of somewhere that I didn't know? For instance the correspondence between locally regular categories and tabular allegories is a good reason we should study tabular allegories.

PS. Should [allegories](/questions/tagged/allegories) be a tag?

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but I find the notion of [bicategory of relations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicategory+of+relations) a bit easier to motivate than allegories precisely because of the modular law in the latter, and a bicategory of relations is equivalent to a unital pretabular allegory.  Of course, YMMV, you may not find the axioms of a bicategory of relations (particularly the Frobenius law) any more justified.